# How can use Box.API with Asp.Net web service?

Tags: asp.net, box-api, boxapiv2

I have used asp.net(c#) web service for my project. I am calling save file function from front end **adobe flex environment**. My files are exists on web service folder.

My **web application** is an **intranet application** and currently used google docs api for uploading and retriving files for the project.

Now i want to use service of box.com and using box.com api, i want to upload and download the files.

***Question:*** In google docs api, i have generated authorization code using login credential that will  help to create token and using this token help me to upload files , download files and create/update/Delete folders.

**How can i will do same for the box.com api ? 
How can i will authorized and create token in my web services ?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at:
https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2

The SDK supports .NET version 4.0 and up. For ease of installation, try pulling the package from nuget.org:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Box.V2/

Examples are available in the readme as well as in the Box.V2.Samples solution folder

HTH

Comment: Thank you for give me a direction, But i want to generate token from webservice call it self.  Is box.com API provide such kind of functionality so i will send box.com credential over API and API give me response with authentication code / token ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not that I know of, as that circumvents the OAuth2 spec. I have heard of work-arounds where people have used a browser control and scraped the DOM for the information they need. This would work, but of course is not recommended or guaranteed to work